# com.ibatis.common.logging.jdk14.Jdk14LoggingImpl error

Tags: ibatis

I developed simple stand alone application using iBATIS framework.I am trying to add one record in database.I have given all the config parameters in SqlMapConfig.xml correctly.But while running the application,
I am getting following error

```
com.ibatis.common.logging.jdk14.Jdk14LoggingImpl error
SEVERE: SimpleDataSource: Error while loading properties. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:265)
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.instantiate(Resources.java:281)
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.initialize(SimpleDataSource.java:199)
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.<init>(SimpleDataSource.java:116)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.datasource.SimpleDataSourceFactory.initialize(SimpleDataSourceFactory.java:31)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser$9.process(SqlMapConfigParser.java:347)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:121)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:105)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:102)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:102)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:72)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:51)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:86)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:63)
    at com.tutorialspoint.ibatis.IbatisInsert.main(IbatisInsert.java:14)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/transactionManager/dataSource/end()'.  Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: Error initializing DataSource.  Could not instantiate DataSourceFactory.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: SimpleDataSource: Error while loading properties. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:89)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientBuilder.java:63)
    at com.tutorialspoint.ibatis.IbatisInsert.main(IbatisInsert.java:14)
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/transactionManager/dataSource/end()'.  Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: Error initializing DataSource.  Could not instantiate DataSourceFactory.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: SimpleDataSource: Error while loading properties. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:53)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser.parse(SqlMapConfigParser.java:86)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/transactionManager/dataSource/end()'.  Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: Error initializing DataSource.  Could not instantiate DataSourceFactory.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: SimpleDataSource: Error while loading properties. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:123)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:105)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:102)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.process(NodeletParser.java:102)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:72)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.parse(NodeletParser.java:51)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: Error initializing DataSource.  Could not instantiate DataSourceFactory.  Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: SimpleDataSource: Error while loading properties. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser$9.process(SqlMapConfigParser.java:354)
    at com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletParser.processNodelet(NodeletParser.java:121)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SimpleDataSource: Error while loading properties. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.initialize(SimpleDataSource.java:210)
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.<init>(SimpleDataSource.java:116)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.datasource.SimpleDataSourceFactory.initialize(SimpleDataSourceFactory.java:31)
    at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.builder.xml.SqlMapConfigParser$9.process(SqlMapConfigParser.java:347)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.classForName(Resources.java:265)
    at com.ibatis.common.resources.Resources.instantiate(Resources.java:281)
    at com.ibatis.common.jdbc.SimpleDataSource.initialize(SimpleDataSource.java:199)
    ... 12 more
```

SqlMapConfig.xml contents are

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sqlMapConfig
PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map Config 2.0//EN"
"http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-config-2.dtd">

<sqlMapConfig>
     <settings useStatementNamespaces="true"/>
     <transactionManager type="JDBC">
        <dataSource type="SIMPLE">
          <property name="JDBC.Driver" 
               value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
          <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL"
               value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empdb"/>
          <property name="JDBC.Username" value="root"/>
          <property name="JDBC.Password" value="root"/>
        </dataSource>
      </transactionManager>
     <sqlMap resource="Employee.xml"/> 
</sqlMapConfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for this problem.this problem was their because I did not include **mysql connector jar**.

Thanks all.